# Media queries inside svg not working as expected

Tags: html, css, svg, media-queries

Consider the following `yellow_submarine.svg` icon:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media(max-height:16px){
                #icon16{display:inline;}
                #icon32{display:none;}
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <image id="icon16" display="none"   width="100%" height="100%" href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
    <image id="icon32" display="inline" width="100%" height="100%" href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

It embeds a 32-by-32 png icon of a submarine with three portholes.
It also embeds a 16-by-16 version of the submarine with two portholes when space is at a premium.

I use the following html code to display the icon:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Small:<span style="width:16px;height:16px;display:inline-block;background:url(yellow_submarine.svg)no-repeat;background-size:100%;"></span>
        Large:<span style="width:32px;height:32px;display:inline-block;background:url(yellow_submarine.svg)no-repeat;background-size:100%;"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**When displayed at 100% zoom level** in both Firefox and Edge, I get the following rendering:

[image: Image at 100% zoom]

**When displayed at 200% zoom level**, I get the following rendering:

[image]

And this is where I get confused. When zoomed at 200% the svg now has 32 device pixels available and should use the 32-by-32 version. But instead it is rescaling the 16-by-16 version.

**What should I put in the media query to test the number of device pixels available?**

Comment: Why would you use SVG to do that?

Comment: @BarryCap I hoped to reduce the number of css styles required. This icon is part of a set containing around 4000 icons. I had a solution like yours using `@media max-resolution` But it requires two styles and When my css processor sees 8000 styles, it breaks appart. I was hopping to reduce the number of style by two.

Comment: Ok, so my answer isn't really good for your thing. Know that it's not a standard behavior to use a different image (e. g. bigger size) when zooming. This is the kind of thing favicons does, but not normally implemented pictures. You will probably need some JavaScript to do this in a clean manner.

Answer (score 4):

When we zoom in a browser it does not change the number of pixels available. It will just make a pixel two times bigger. That's the reason why when you zoom by 200% it will still use the 16×16 version of the SVG but two times bigger.

If you want to do this you should use any other approach.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "any other approach" part please? I am new to html/js/css/svg development and have now idea how to do it.

Comment: HI @Arnaud both of your images are exactly same and in case of svg size doesn't matter. Can you please explain what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I would like to display the most appropriate png image based on the number of physical pixels available. If there are more than 16 physical pixels use the 32-by-32 image otherwise use the 16-by-16 image. But it seems I am stuck with css pixels here.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do it with CSS only (please view the result full page for best results):

```css
#icon {
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  #icon {
    content: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
    Icon: <image id="icon" style="width:16px;height:16px" />
</p>
```

I've made an alternate solution [here](https://codepen.io/barrycap/pen/MWpBxpy).

Comment: It seems that setting `::content` for replaced element (what `img` or it's alter-ego `image` is) does not currently work in Firefox.

Comment: Yes this works. I had already found this one before posting my question though.